# What does it mean by 'time' in a random process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I understand that

> A random process is a series of random variables which is composed of
>   two components:
>
> 1. time
> 2. values
>
> Both time and values can be either discrete and continuous.

I have proper/enough examples in my hand. I just need a 'properly expressible' definition of time without formal notation.

A general answer would be

> time is the **index** of random variables in the series.

this is not easy to imagine/perceive.

So, my question here is, what is the definition of **time** here?

Comment: You understand this. Have you seen examples of this now? The first example should be right after where you saw the definition. Remember, to get the concept well you need to see examples : they give you your first impression of things.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, I have proper examples in my hand. I just need a 'properly expressible' definition of $time$ without formal notation.